# Resources for mediation analysis

Tags: regression, references, econometrics, mediation

I am looking for resources to study mediation analysis. But to be specific, What I am instrusted in is something like the following. Say we have an outcome y, and some treatment (or shock x) which affects many different variables, each in term have some theoretical effect on y. Say z1, z2, and z3. So you can think of something like an intent to treat/reduced form relationship of the form:

$y = \beta + \beta1X + \epsilon$

, and then y is also a function of mediators, z1-z3 as in $y = f(z1,z2,z3)$. the treatment X theoretically affects y by shifting z1-z3, and each in turn then affect y. I have established effects of the ITT/reduced form relationship, as well as effects of x on z1-z3, and wish to decompose how each contribute in their effect on y, or the strength of each channel. I am curious of formal ways of testing this, as well as what assumptions must be made in order to disentangle such effects.

Let me know if that makes sense!